# Checking string value in a string using c#

Tags: c#

I have following code in my project

```
var ReturnStr = Final_BOM.Tables[0].Rows[0]["NEW_BOM_IDS"].ToString();
```

the above line returns "12,13" but some times only "12"

```
var ReturnBOM = dsBOMDEfault.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Item_ID"].ToString();
```

the above line returns "14,15,13".

I want to check ReturnBOM values in ReturnStr

Can any one help how to check

Comment: So, you want to check what values of `ReturnBom` are present in `ReturnStr`?

Comment: before ask please read the doc : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
 have good working.

Comment: yes, you are correct

Comment: `ReturnBOM.Split(',').Any(x => ReturnStr.Split(',').Contains(x))`

Comment: or `ReturnBOM.Split(',').Intersect(ReturnStr.Split(',')).Count() > 0`

Comment: if it has only single value, split has no effect

Comment: If it has only single value, split will return an array with the single value

Comment: Why is that a problem? What values do you expect returned when ReturnStr = "12,13" & what do you expect for "12"?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [intersect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136(v=vs.110).aspx):

Here a quick one-liner:

```
var results = ReturnStr.Split(',').Select(int.Parse)
    .Intersect(ReturnBOM.Split(',').Select(int.Parse))
```

[Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0QvxoT):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var ReturnStr = "12,13";
        var ReturnBOM = "14,15,13";

        // Convert string to array with Split(',')
        // if you dont want int just remove `.Select(int.Parse)`
        var ReturnStrElements = ReturnStr.Split(',').Select(int.Parse);
        var ReturnBOMElements = ReturnBOM.Split(',').Select(int.Parse);

        // Keep only common elements
        var results = ReturnStrElements.Intersect(ReturnBOMElements);

        foreach(var item in results)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
}
```

- We use `Split()` to convert a string to an array where the delimiter is ','
- [Optional] We use `Select(int.Parse)` to convert each element from string to int.
- We use `Intersect()` to keep only common elements

Answer (score 1):

If i understanded rights:

```
        string[] returnBomVals = ReturnBom.Split(',');
        string[] returnStrVals = ReturnStr.Split(',');
        foreach (var vals in returnStrVals)
        {
            foreach (var strVals in returnBomVals)
            {
                if (ReturnStr.Equals(vals))
                {
                    //Do Actions
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: if ReturnStr is the following value: "123" and ReturnBom is "12", your code will give a false positive.

Answer (score 1):

Use LINQ.

```
using System.Linq;
```

The below code will give you an IEnumerable of String with the values you are looking for.

```
var inBoth = ReturnStr.Split(',').Intersect(ReturnBOM.Split(','))
```

You may then iterate through the values, cast them to Int32 or do whatever action you want.